# Portable module on Angular?

Tags: angular

How is a module created on the angular that can be used in future on other sites on the hangar?

I make a small application on the angular, it receives information from the api. In the future, this application will be embedded in different sites that will pass certain parameters for api requests.

I don’t really understand what form the final module should look like? I understand that the application itself is the module. But how will it be embedded in other sites? Do I need to definitely build it? How will the interaction with package.json work? anyone who has a similar experience, please share.

Comment: that not a module but a library : https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Comment: If the configuration is only for the module, you can pass a configuration object. If the configuration is global for the whole application, you can provide a configuration module or a configuration file. In this way, you keep separate application logic and application data